# Webservice on bluemix that supports http posts

Tags: java, web-services, websphere, ibm-cloud

i am new to the bluemix platform. i am trying to create a webservice that comunicates with a database, both stored on bluemix . What i want is to send http post requests to the webservice from outside of bluemix. The webservice should do something on the database and then retrieve the answer to the "client application.

To achieve this , i added an SQL Database and an WebSphere Application Server on Cloud to a Java Liberty starter Web Project.

The problem is that i can't bind the "webservice "(websphere ) to the application(Java Liberty starter) ...Am i doing this wrong ?. Any help would be greatly appreciated , thank you

Answer (score 5):

The WebSphere Application Server on Cloud is not a service that you bind to an application as it is essentially an environment on its own but managed by IBM. With this service you get access to a install of WebSphere Application Server on a shared VM and have root access to the filesystem. From that install you can then deploy applications like you would with an on-prem version of WebSphere Application Server.

An application (your webservice) running on Bluemix using the Liberty for Java Buildpack is running on a Liberty server already and can be bound to the SQLDB service, there is no need for the WebSphere Application Server on Cloud service.

I would recommend that you just work with your Liberty Buildpack application and bind this to your SQLDB service rather than look at using the WebSphere Application Server on Cloud service.